# 36.0.0 is not valid sdk version. options are 43.0.0,35.0.0,33.0.0, unversioned

Tags: react-native, expo

When I upgrade expo-cli to the latest version 36.0.0 I get this error running on android emulator "36.0.0 is not valid sdk version. options are 43.0.0,35.0.0,33.0.0, unversioned"

How to solve this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to reinstall or update expo app in your mobile.

Answer (score 10):

You need to update your expo version. Try following steps. Let me know if this doesn't work

```
npm install (for node module)
expo update
npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
npm start
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use command 
`expo client:install:android` to upgrade your expo client app